# SQL Advanced SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
translations
+---------+----------------+----------+---------+
| id_user | id_translation | referrer | id_word |
+---------+----------------+----------+---------+
|       1 |              3 |     NULL |       4 |
|       1 |             17 |     NULL |       3 |
|       2 |             17 |     NULL |       5 |
|       2 |             17 |     NULL |       1 |
|       2 |             17 |     NULL |       7 |
```

```
words
+----+------+
| id | word |
+----+------+
|  4 | out  |
+----+------+
```

```
users_translations
+---------+----------------+----------+---------+
| id_user | id_translation | referrer | id_word |
+---------+----------------+----------+---------+
|       1 |             17 |     1    |       4 |
|       2 |             17 |     2    |       4 |
|       3 |             18 |     NULL |       4 |
```

I need to select all `translations` for current `word` and `id_translation`, but if in the row `referrer = 1` (current `user`), then I don't need another results (`translations` from another users for current `word`), if there is no `referrer = 1`, show all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.*, `ut`.`id_user` AS tuser 
FROM translations AS t
LEFT JOIN users_translations AS ut ON `t`.`id` = `ut`.`id_translation`
INNER JOIN words ON `words`.`id` = `ut`.`id_word` OR `words`.`id` = `t`.`id_word`
WHERE (`word` = 'help')
ORDER BY `t`.`translation` ASC


+----+-------------+---------+---------+-------+
| id | translation | id_word | id_user | tuser |
+----+-------------+---------+---------+-------+
| 17 | допомагати  |       4 |       1 |     2 |
| 17 | допомагати  |       4 |       1 |     1 |
```

First row doesn't need, because we have `tuser = 1`. When there is no `tuser = 1`, all results should be returned.

I don't understand how to build select statement and I will be very appreciative that somebody shows me how to make it work.

Comment: sorry could not understand exactly what you want. why do you have two referrers columns?

Comment: what is t.id?  in query

Comment: translations and users_translations have the same structure, table translations contains only unique translations, but users_translations allow to add the same translation for different words. I tried to avoid duplicate entries, but it's doesn't matter because question is in query and in the result it returns. t is short name for translations table, ut for users_translations table

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind

```
--add this to your where clause
    id_user <= 
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM translations WHERE id_user = 1 AND id_word = words.id_word) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM translations)
        END
```

Comment: You gave me a food for thinking. I'll try to check if this is working later. Thanks!